# How to get max property value in an object with duplicate property name?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Suppose I have an array with the following values:

Array name is *"subscribers"*

```
1: {month: "2019-07-24", subs: 2}
2: {month: "2019-07-31", subs: 3}
3: {month: "2019-08-01", subs: 2}
4: {month: "2019-08-02", subs: 3}
5: {month: "2019-08-05", subs: 3}
6: {month: "2019-08-08", subs: 4}
7: {month: "2019-08-14", subs: 5}
8: {month: "2019-08-20", subs: 7}
9: {month: "2019-08-23", subs: 7}
10: {month: "2019-08-28", subs: 8}
11: {month: "2019-08-29", subs: 11}
12: {month: "2019-09-02", subs: 2}
13: {month: "2019-09-03", subs: 2}
14: {month: "2019-09-04", subs: 3}
15: {month: "2019-09-05", subs: 5}
16: {month: "2019-09-06", subs: 5}
17: {month: "2019-09-09", subs: 6}
18: {month: "2019-09-10", subs: 7}
19: {month: "2019-09-11", subs: 8}
20: {month: "2019-09-12", subs: 9}
```

My question is, how can I get the highest subs by monthly?

Expected output:

```
0: {month: "July", subs: 3}
1: {month: "August", subs: 11}
2: {month: "September", subs: 9}
```

I tried using array.map, but I cannot get the expected output. Also I tried using Math.max, but I cannot seem to use it in an object.

```
var getMonthlyValues = subscribers.map(value => {   
        var obj = {};
        var dateName = new Date(value.period).toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
        obj = {month:dateName, subs:value.monthly}
        return obj;
    })
```

I can do this if for example these are from database with columns as month and sub, with their respective values. But how can I do this on pure JS?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: is the array sorted? are the `subs` always same or increasing? what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz I've updated the question with what I've done. The array is not sorted, and the subs may increase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and collect the maximum `subs` for every `month`.

In steps:

- Reduce the array by taking a `Map` as accumulator and take the grouping property `month` as key. As value take the maximum from either a previously stored value or zero and the actual value.

  If negative values or zeros are available use a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), like

  ```
    m.has(month) ? Math.max(m.get(month), subs) : subs
  ```
- Take the list of key/value pairs and return an array of objects with custom named properties with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and a mapping function.

```js
var data = [{ month: "July", subs: 2 }, { month: "July", subs: 3 }, { month: "August", subs: 2 }, { month: "August", subs: 3 }, { month: "August", subs: 3 }, { month: "August", subs: 4 }, { month: "August", subs: 5 }, { month: "August", subs: 7 }, { month: "August", subs: 7 }, { month: "August", subs: 8 }, { month: "August", subs: 11 }, { month: "September", subs: 2 }, { month: "September", subs: 2 }, { month: "September", subs: 3 }, { month: "September", subs: 5 }, { month: "September", subs: 5 }, { month: "September", subs: 6 }, { month: "September", subs: 7 }, { month: "September", subs: 8 }, { month: "September", subs: 9 }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce(
            (m, { month, subs }) => m.set(month, Math.max(m.get(month) || 0, subs)),
            new Map
        ),
        ([month, subs]) => ({ month, subs })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Gives the result as I wanted. So it's a combination of reduce and Map? I just have to study this Map as this is new to me. Thanks!

Comment: right. `Map` is for grouping and `Array.from` gives the result set a proper format.

Comment: Can you please explain your code , I became fan of this syntax . @NinaScholz .